# Can't Run Hello World program in Tornadofx

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and I'm trying to run a simple hello world program using tornadofx. The file is called hello.kt and I'm attempting to compile and run it using just the terminal.

It seems to compile just fine by running

`kotlinc -cp tornadofx.jar hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar`

But when I try to run it by entering

`java -jar hello.jar`

I get a NoClassDefFoundError error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tornadofx/View
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at HelloKt.main(hello.kt:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tornadofx.View
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 13 more
```

Here's the file:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox
import tornadofx.App
import tornadofx.View

class HelloWorld : View() {
  override val root = HBox(Label("Hello world!"))
}

class HelloWorldApp : App() {
  override val primaryView = HelloWorld::class
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val window = HelloWorldApp()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Oracle JDK, which comes with JavaFX, or install the JavaFX OpenJDK bundles in Ubuntu. I would recommend the Oracle JDK.

Additionally, JavaFX Applications has to be launched, you can't simply instantiate the App class. See below.

The syntax in your example code is very outdated - did you find this in the guide or somewhere else? This is the current syntax for your code example, including the correct launch command.

```
class HelloWorld : View() {
  override val root = hbox(label("Hello world!"))
}

class HelloWorldApp : App(HelloWorld::class)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<HelloWorldApp>(args)
}
```

Comment: I have both openjdk 1.8 and openjfx installed. I tried compiling your code and it gave me an error involving java byte code so I compiled it using the tag `-jvm-target 1.8` and it worked, but when attempting to run the jar file it gave me the same result.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you running against? Please note that TornadoFX is not compatible with JDK9, you need the latest version of JDK8.